# How to assign a value to more than one element of an array using loops?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a program that makes each month of the year an array. Each month has different charges, some occur every month, some only occur every few months. We have to write this program using only loops, so I'm wondering how I can assign a certain value to multiple months (for example, + $200 for January and June) using only 1 "for" statement.

Below is the code I have so far dealing with this array:

```
//This line creates an array for 12 months and a variable called "month"
Double[] yearlyExpenses = new Double[12];
int month;

//These lines assign values to the correct months using loops
for (month = 0; month < yearlyExpenses.length; month++) {
  yearlyExpenses[month] = rent + miscExpenses;
}
for (month = 0; month == 0 & 5; month++) {
  yearlyExpenses[month] = yearlyExpenses[month] + 200;
}
```

You can see that the second "for" statement is where I'm trying to assign the value to the two months.

The code works fine if I were to just say "month == 0", but when I try to include a different month using "&" or "&&" or anything of the sort, I get a compiling error.

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm fairly new to Java. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even if it wasn't a compiler error it would be a logical error. It can't equal both 0 and 5 at the same time. That being said you need to provide `month ==` to both.

Comment: You can't do month == 0 && 5. It has to be month == 0 && month == 5. In this case it should be month == 0 || month == 5

Comment: @d.j.brown What number is **both** `0` and `5`?

Comment: Edited, was just addressing the compile error

Comment: Please don't put the status "[SOLVED]" in the title. Show that it's solved by accepting the answer that helped the most.

Answer (score 1):

Your second loop wouldn't work like you expect, instead perform the math in your first loop. Something like,

```
for (month = 0; month < yearlyExpenses.length; month++) {
  yearlyExpenses[month] = rent + miscExpenses;
  if (month == 0 || month == 5) {
    yearlyExpenses[month] = yearlyExpenses[month] + 200;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This one ended up working the best. There are different charges that apply to different months so using multiple "if" statements worked out perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you need just for month 0 and 5 try this

```
for (month = 0; month < 6; month+=5) {
      yearlyExpenses[month] = yearlyExpenses[month] + 200;
    }
```